# Can I transfer private data of my Android application to inspect?

Tags: android

I want to transfer a file created with `getAppContext().getDir("myfolder",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` from my Android device to my computer so I can inspect the created file.

Is this possible without root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends whether your file was created under `/data` in which case you need to be root to access it. If it was created on your SD-Card, you can simply mount the phone on the pc and access it.